# 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'LineEdit'

Tags: python, qlineedit

> def browse_base(self):
> option=QFileDialog.Options()
> file=QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(widget,"Open Single File","CC","All Files(*)",options=option)
> self.base_addr.lineEdit.setText(file[0])

I have a problem here: 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'LineEdit'
And i don`t know what i need to do

Comment: What is your question ? Could you please format your code so we can actually read it ? Thanks

Comment: oh, yes, sorry.

Comment: Formatting should still be improved, I have a very hard time reading...

Comment: If that solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer using the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're assuming that `self.base_addr` has a `lineEdit` attribute that is a `QLineEdit`, but it seems that `self.base_addr` itself is already a `QLineEdit` (which has no `lineEdit` attribute), so that using just `self.base_addr.setText(file[0])` should probably work.

However, this may just be the tip of the iceberg, but it is very hard to tell from the code in your question.